# Why do different operating systems install packages from CRAN differently?

Tags: r, cran, install.packages

When I `install.package()` in R on a Windows machine, the package downloads from CRAN and installs. When I do the same on a Linux box, the package usually has to compile (at least, I assume that's what going with all those `g++` lines that scroll past).

Why is the package installation method different on Windows?

Other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170043/r-apt-get-install-r-cran-foo-vs-install-packagesfoo) and [their answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812265/install-r-packages-from-binary-in-ubuntu-lucid?rq=1) make it clear that using different methods and repositories for Linux particularly, enables users to get more/different packages (particularly using the cran2deb repository). My question is more theoretical in nature: why is the default choice in Windows to download precompiled (binary?) packages whereas the default in Linux seems to be to compile packages from source?

Or to put it another way (based on Dirk's assertion in the second link above), why doesn't CRAN offer binary packages for Unix-type operating systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Windows binaries will work on all versions of Windows.

Ditto for the key / current versions of MacOS: the provided binaries work.

Linux, sadly, is more complicated because the different distros lay things out differently. Something I build on Ubuntu or Debian (or, more specifically, a particular release version thereof) may not even work on other releases of the same distro, let alone other distro.  In some cases you can get binaries.  At some point I (co-)owned a build service for all of CRAN, but it died/broke. All doable with effort, but ... some effort.

So from source it is. That use to be the standard anyway which "Unix" was a catch-all phrase covering SunOS/Solaris, AIX, *BSD, SGI and on and on. Often even with different processors.  So source.

There have been attempts to provide 'universal binaries': flatpack and snap are two more recent examples.  And then there is of course Docker.